# How do I run Python scripts through the Python shell using RobotFramework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I’ve inherited a Python Automation Framework with dozens of Python scripts that we are looking to reuse to avoid rewriting them in the new RobotFramework framework.

The main script I’m looking to run:

• opens a Python shell

• sends some output

• takes an argument (True/False: 1/0)

• runs the rest of the script.

The scripts have been added to my framework in a separate folder called ‘PythonLibraries’. When called upon manually through the terminal, the scripts work. They run, ask for the arguments and continue with the rest of the script so there doesn’t seem to be any issues with the script itself.

What I’m looking for is to automate them using RobotFramework. The idea being to import the python script to my .robot file, create a keyword to run the script and have it take an argument, and save the output to a variable or a file so I can review what’s being outputted.

I’ve being trying now for a few days to get this working with no luck. I’ve been experimenting with the ‘Process’ library, however there is very little support/examples online to help with this. When trying to run the script, the terminal hangs and doesn’t output anything. So either my script is wrong or I’m doing something wrong.

Here’s the python script I’m looking to run.

```
import uuid
import BTR_ble_sim as BTR

from libs.BLE.script_config import read_serial_port_name, ask_for_serial_number
from libs.BLE.host_bgapi_psrecords import delete_all_bonds

DONGLE_SERIAL_PORT = read_serial_port_name()
SERIAL_NUMBER = "BT10" + str(uuid.uuid4().get_hex().upper()[0:3])
print "Device is broadcasting on: " + SERIAL_NUMBER

btr = BTR.GmInterface(DONGLE_SERIAL_PORT,SERIAL_NUMBER)
btr.delete_bonds()
btr.start_comm_with_time_sync()
```

Should I edit the python script to become a function that takes an argument? Would that make more sense, or is there a more straight forward way of doing this? Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: As you've seen the Process library doesn't have an api to work with stdin; you could go with piping, running a command like `echo "my input" | python your_script.py`, but it will start getting complicated when there's multiple inputs expected, or a choice system. Frankly in you place, yes, I'd migrate the scripts to become functions (while preserving the cli form with a `if __name__ == '__main__' `construct); you'll eventually need to do refactoring anyways, to get python3 support.